# Iterating through a 2D Array with a for loop

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to create an associative table on a sheet that is pulling in data from a different sheet. By associative I mean, if the data is changed in the source data sheet, it would be reflected on the new sheet. I also want to only have the new sheet's table to be contingent on having a certain unique value. In my case, I want to pull up information related to a part number. The original source data will have many rows that contain the same part number, but I only care to display one of them.

So far, this is what I have:

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim bDimen As Byte, i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    If IsError(UBound(arr, 2)) Then bDimen = 1 Else bDimen = 2
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case bDimen
    Case 1
        On Error Resume Next
        IsInArray = Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Case 2
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            On Error Resume Next
            IsInArray = Application.Match(stringToBeFound, 
Application.index(arr, , i), 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If IsInArray = True Then Exit For
        Next
    End Select
End Function

Sub Part_Separator()
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Set Source = Sheets("Part Tracking Scorecard")
    Dim ref1(), ref2() As Variant
    Dim row, index, lastrow, lastcolumn As Integer

    row = 92
    lastrow = 866
    lastcolumn = 84

    ref1 = Source.Range(Source.Cells(row, 1), Source.Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
    ReDim ref2(UBound(ref1, 1), UBound(ref1, 2))

    For index = 0 To (lastrow - row)
        If IsInArray(ref1(index, 6).Value, ref2) Then
            index = index + 1
        Else
            ref2(index) = ref1(index) 'copy the entire row from source to ref2
            index = index + 1
        End If
    Next index

    Dim NewFile As Worksheet
    Set NewFile = Sheets("Unique Parts")

    Dim ref2dimension_x, ref2dimension_y As Integer 'find dimensions of ref2 array
    ref2dimension_x = UBound(ref2, 1) - LBound(ref2, 1) + 1
    ref2dimension_y = UBound(ref2, 2) - LBound(ref2, 2) + 1

    For index = 2 To ref2dimension_x 'go through entire new sheet and set values
        For index2 = 1 To ref2dimension_y
            NewFile.Cells(index, index2).Value = ref2(index - 1, index2)
        Next index2
    Next index

    Erase ref1()
    Erase ref2() 'free up the space occupied by these arrays

End Sub
```

My issue when I run this, I get an error at the first for loop where I'm trying to iterate through my ref1 array, which is the array with all my source data.  The error says that my subscript is out of range.  This loop is suppose to check if the specific value is in my ref2 array for uniqueness. If the specific value is found, go onto the next row, if not add the row of values associated to the value I'm checking to ref2.

Comment: At this line, `If IsInArray(ref1(index, 6).Value, ref2) Then` ref2 hasn't been defined or even dimensioned.

Comment: ref2 has been initalized as a variant, and the function IsInArray might need to be changed to reflect a 2D array. I'm not really sure how to change it though, since the function originally was made for 1D to check if an element was in the array

Comment: No, this line `Dim ref1(), ref2() As Variant` declares it, but when you declare an array with open brackets you must use Redim in the code to size it.

Comment: Could you happen to know how I could go about resizing an array that should have a variable size? I'm not really use to VBA and mainly code in Python, so the limitations on lists/arrays are new to me.

Comment: If it should be the same size as ref1 then you could do `redim ref2(ubound(ref1,1),ubound(ref1,2))`, but IsInArray will only work for a 1D array.

Comment: I changed the IsInArray, and resized it as shown in my edits and the issue still occurs, what else could the issue be?